# How can I can clone or ghost my system drive to restore it to a bigger HD?

Tags: backup, system, clone

How can I can clone or ghost my Ubuntu System drive to restore it to a bigger HD?
Something like Norton Ghost does with NTFS or FAT on Windows.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/) is the closest free option to Ghost.

The underlying tools it uses, `partimage` and `ntfsclone`, understand the underlying filesystem.  So unlike a simple low-level copy (`dd`) which copies all bytes, they only copy the used space on the filesystem and its metadata.  This results in a much smaller disk image.

Comment: Do you mean like. If i have 40GB disk, and my system is using 10GB and 30GB is free. while using dd it will write 40GB to given usb/dvd/cd? Or it will only write 10GB?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to move your data to a new harddrive, the [Simple Backup Suite](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BackupYourSystem/SimpleBackupSuite) can make it very easy for you. Just backup your data, then install Ubuntu onto the new hard-drive and restore from your backup.

If what you really want is a perfect transfer of data from your old harddrive to your new one, you can use the "dd" command-line tool to easily transfer the data. There's a [great discussion of this technique](https://serverfault.com/questions/4906/using-dd-for-disk-cloning) on Server Fault.

Comment: *`The stability and reliability of this package is questionable. As of 6/14/2011 there were 48 open bugs and little sign of development. A second bug reporting site shows signs of development.`* (signs are dead in the second site as well)

Answer (score 0):

I was half way through a response when I found <strike>[this page](http://www.sysdesign.ca/guides/partitions.html)</strike> <sup>[mirror](http://web.archive.org/web/20101025032738/http://www.sysdesign.ca/guides/partitions.html)</sup>.

The classical unix way is a tool called "dd". The page explains how to use it.

Comment: I just took a look at the SimpleBackupSuite that Ryan mentioned, it looks pretty awesome actually.